Django complex relation with joins
I have the following models:
class Position(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField()

class Metric(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField()

class PositionKPI(BaseModel):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    metric = models.ForeignKey(Metric)
    expectation = models.FloatField()

class Employee(BaseModel):
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)

class EmployeeKPI(BaseModel):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    metric = models.ForeignKey(Metric)
    value = models.FloatField()

    def kpi(self):
        return PositionKPI.objects.filter(position=self.employee.position, metric=self.metric).first()

I believe it's possible to rewrite the kpi method as a relation.
In SQL it would look something like this:
select
  positionkpi.* 
from employeekpi 
  join employee on employee.id = employeekpi.employee_id
  join positionkpi on positionkpi.id = employee.position_id
      and positionkpi.metric_id = employeekpi.metric_id

Please advise how to do it

Is it possible to explain what you are trying to do (not that much how) you are trying to do that?

@willeM_VanOnsem I'm trying to achieve a more complex join than just by using 1 foreign key column

That EmployeeKPI looks like a ManyToMany custom through model.

@AKX Yes, it looks like it, but I don't know how to specify the join condition

You can retrieve such records with an F-object [Django-doc]:
from django.db.models import F

PositionKPI.objects.filter(employee__position__metric_id=F('metric_id'))

This one is the option. I wanted to use it as a relation to be compatible with select_related

You can add .select_related(..) clauses, but .select_related(..) is not necessary for JOINs. This is a common misconception.

It looks like it's the best we can do with Django now.  I used to work with RoR, which had a more powerful has-many-through association, but such a case was also impossible. Thank you

You could try something like this, but in this case kpi property return value of expectation field instead of PositionKPI instance
class EmployeeKPIQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def with_kpi(self):
        position_kpi_subquery = PositionKPI.objects.filter(
            position=OuterRef('employee__position'),
            metric=OuterRef('metric')
        ).values('expectation')[:1]

        return self.annotate(
            _kpi=Subquery(position_kpi_subquery, output_field=FloatField())
        )


class EmployeeKPI(BaseModel):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    metric = models.ForeignKey(Metric)
    value = models.FloatField()

    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(EmployeeKPIQuerySet)()

    def kpi(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_kpi'):
            return self._kpi
        return PositionKPI.objects.filter(position=self.employee.position, metric=self.metric).first().expectation



PositionKPI.objects.with_kpi() # instead of PositionKPI.objects.all()


thanks! I'll combine this approach with the manager to simplify working with select_related and will be able to solve the problem

Try to use ChatGPT. Its help to write annotations and complex queries with django ORM
